# Creating video with multiple audios and one still image for YouTube

Tags: linux, bash, video, ffmpeg, youtube

I want to create many videos with multiple audio streams and one single picture.

For example I have

- `song1.mp3`
- `song2.mp3`
- `song3.mp3`

and one single picture. What I need to do is to create many videos and name these videos as: `song1.mp4`, `song2.mp4`, `song3.mp4`

I want to create many videos at once. I have this script for only one picture and one mp3, but I need to create bulk videos.

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -shortest -r 0.1 -i online.mp3 -i imagen.png -ab 128k output.avi
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 3):

First off, you need to reorder your ffmpeg options a bit. The `-loop 1` should come right before the input image, and the `-r 0.1` should ideally go as an output option *after* the image. See more on the [FFmpeg wiki about creating a slideshow from images](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images).

Then, make sure you run a recent version of ffmpeg. [Download one here](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) and do not use the one you installed with `apt-get` – it's very outdated.

Also, you want to use H.264 and AAC as video and audio codec, respectively, with MP4 as a container, not the MPEG-4 and MP3 combination in AVI that you will get with your current command.

Loop over all MP3 files, strip the extension, then run the ffmpeg script:

```
for f in *.mp3; do
    # create output filename songX.mp4
    name="${f%%.mp3}.mp4"
    # run ffmpeg command
    ffmpeg -loop 1 -i imagen.png -i "$f" \
      -r 0.1 -shortest \
      -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a aac -strict experimental \
      -crf 18 -b:a 128k "$name"
done
```

What I also added is:

- CRF (constant rate factor) sets the video quality (use something between 18 and 28, lower is better)
- an explicit conversion to [4:2:0 subsampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_subsampling) – otherwise you'll get 4:4:4 if you have PNG as input, and that cannot be played back in all players